# Python REST server to interact with ongoing subprocess

Tags: python, rest, python-asyncio, background-process

Could someone offer guidance on the high-level technologies/approach needed to accomplish the following. (Note that this is just a contrived/simplified scenario that parallels what I'd really like to do. I'm just avoiding all the unnecessary details about the actual background task):

1. Python-based REST server
2. Ongoing (doesn't end) background task that takes commands via stdin and outputs via stdout
3. User can use the REST server API to ask the background task something, and get a response.

Example:

- Background task that is just counting (for example, incrementing its count by one, each second). User can, via REST, ask what the count of the background task is at the moment.

What I (might) know:

- Use a basic web server framework (Flask, FastAPI - both of which I know very little about)
- Use the asyncio library to run a subprocess (or do I use built-in features of one of the above web server technologies?)
- I'm aware of technologies like Celery, but I'm hoping to avoid having to learn that too.

Ideally, I'd love a minimally functional example (i.e. single REST endpoint in, say, Flask, how to kick off the background task that will just keep going and not time out, and finally how to asynchronously interact with that one background task each time a request comes through the REST server.

So:

1. Start web server with single 'get count' endpoint
2. Start background counting task (on its own it just outputs to stdout, but I guess through some PIPE we could get that if we want (to read a line), or use some stdin PIPE to ask the program for its latest count
3. User hits the REST endpoint
4. Return a line from the counting background task

Comment: Here at Stack Overflow we do not offer guidance, we are answering specific questions. Do you have one?

Comment: How to interact with an ongoing background process when using Flask or FastAPI.

Comment: Make it specific by showing us what you have tried so far!

Comment: for counting you could use database - background taks save current value in database and other programs (like REST) can get current value from database. As I know Celery works this way. It sends information/tasks to database and workers periodciallu check if there is new data/tasks in database and get it and later they put result in the same place. And at the same time REST can periodically check if there is result.